# IDisposable and Asynchronous Processing (SmtpClient.SendAsync)

Tags: .net, asynchronous, smtpclient

Reviewing the MSDN docs for [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient), I noticed that the example code looks like this:

```
client.SendAsync(message, userState);
// More stuff
message.Dispose();
```

The call to SendAsync could take significant time to complete.  How is it that *message* remains in a useful state if it is disposed on the line following the *SendAsync* call?

Further, *SmtpClient* implements *IDisposable*.  The MSDN example should more property be formed like

```
using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient())
{
    // Initialize client and create the message
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to))
    {
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);
        // More stuff
    }
}
```

So not only would *message.Dispose()* be called while *client.SendAsync()* is potentially still executing, but *client.Dispose()* would be called as well.

How is it that *client* remains in a useful state for the completion of *SendAsync()* if *Dispose()* is called almost immediately after the call to *SendAsync()*?

Or, is the MSDN example just wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dispose it only after async send operation completed or canceled.
So dispose it in this situation in SendCompleted event handler

Look at sample in MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx

Or this blog post

http://leedumond.com/blog/new-in-net-4-dont-forget-to-dispose-your-smtpclient-instances/

Example on MSDN is bad. And you are not the first person with this problem look at comments there:

> Bad Example
>
> After laying out the important reasons to Dispose() your
> SmtpClient, this example does not do so.  Also, Dispose() is called on
> MailMessage possibly before SendAync has completed, which I'm quite
> sure has caused exceptions for me.  You can dispose of the MailMessage
> in the SendComplete event handler however.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, using a wait event:

```
        // Initialize client and create the message
        using (var emailWait = new AutoResetEvent(false))
        using (var client = new SmtpClient())
        using (var message = new MailMessage(from, to))
        {
            client.SendCompleted += (sender, e) => emailWait.Set();
            client.SendAsync(message, userState);
            // More stuff
            emailWait.WaitOne();
        }
```